# Use path of subdirectory for svn:ignore property

Tags: svn

I only want to set the `svn:ignore` property in the project root directory, so I only have to keep track of one place. So I tried to include `test/test_samples/*_dex.txt`, but the file is still listed under non-versioned when I try to commit.

To prove that generally speaking I included `*_dex.txt` only in the `test/test_samples` directory, which worked as expected. I also tried / and , as I am working on Windows.

Any other idea how to solve this?

Comment: Or is that not possible with SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion expects you to set file names or wildcards *per directory*. So setting a path in the project's root will not work.

Quoting from [Ignoring Unversioned Items in the Red Bean Book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) (emphasis mine):

> The other way [i.e. setting svn:ignore] makes use of Subversion's *directory property* support [...]. Both of the mechanisms use *file patterns* (strings of literal and special wildcard characters used to match against *filenames*) to decide which files to ignore.

While it does not state that the `svn:ignore` property was *not* inherited from parent directories, the only property that *is* explicitly inherited is `svn:mergeinfo` (see [Mergeinfo](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo))

I would guess that subversion simply looks at the `svn:ignore` property of the current directory without bothering to go up the tree.

For the sake of completeness, there are also *global ignore* patterns (mostly used for editors' backup and swap files). It seems unlikely these are a good solution in your case.

So you will have to go for the decentralized solution and set the `svn:ignore` property on directory `test/test_samples` to `*_dex.txt`.

Comment: That's what I figured... Thanks for the confirmation.