# Adding files and directories to ignore list in Subversive for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have SVN running on a remote Apache server with repositories that I've created.

On my Windows 11 PC I have Eclipse 2023-03 with the Subversive 4.8 plugin.

On the server, I created a new blank repo. In Eclipse, I added a new PHP project with a single `index.php` file. I then shared the project using Team->Share.

Next, I copied over my project files from my temp directory into the workspace. My project has a number of files that I don't want committed to the repo. For example: `upload/<any>.PDF`. However, there is an `upload/index.php` which I do need.

Going to Team menu, the "Add to svn:ignore" is only shown for top level directories. For sub-directories and files, the option is greyed out.

[image: svn:ignore greyed out]

I then opened Project Properties->SVN Info. I tried to edit the `svn:ignore` list there but if I type \ or /, for e.g. `upload/*.pdf`, it says: You should use only ? or * to specify the pattern.

[image: Specifying manually doesn't work]

The existing entry says "application logs". I don't want to ignore the directory itself, but the `*.log` files within it.

BTW, adding `*.pdf` to global ignore list is not workable as there are PDF files in other directories that do need to be versioned.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the directories (using either the `svn add` command or the *Add to Version Control...* context menu entry) you copied into your working copy before you can set the `svn:ignore` property on them.

I suspect the respective menu entry is greyed out in your subdirectories because they're not under version control and no properties can be set on them.

Quoting from the [Red Bean Book, chapter Ignoring Unversioned Items](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) (emphasis mine):

> When found *on a versioned directory*, the `svn:ignore` property is expected to contain a list of newline-delimited file patterns that Subversion should use to determine ignorable objects *in that same directory*.

So two things follow:

- You need to add your directories to version control first as said above.
- Furthermore, `svn:ignore` property is supposed to be in the respective directory, i.e. setting it to something like `path/to/a/file` does *not* work. You're supposed to set `svn:ignore` to `file` in directory `path/to/a`. Also see [Use path of subdirectory for svn:ignore property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76323018/use-path-of-subdirectory-for-svnignore-property)

Once you've verified that the set of files you added and ignored is correct and complete, you can `svn commit` all of them creating a new revision.

Comment: I am aware that the ````svn ignore```` command would work on a command line. I have used it on Linux machines. I don't have any svn client on my Windows machine other than the Subversive plugin for Eclipse. Is there any option within Eclipse/Subversive to achieve this?
Also, the project is under version control. I can select any top-level directory and see the ignore option. In directories under the top level, this is greyed out.

Comment: Yes, the top level directories have not yet been committed. If I do the commit that would send all log, pdf, etc. to the server and the documentation says that you can't ignore any file once it has been committed.

Comment: Whatever the command line client may or may not do, your IDE plugin either does the same or it's broken. You might try the "Add to Version Control..." context menu entry that is not greyed out in your screenshot. I never said anything about committing. You `svn add` first, once your satisfied you `svn commit`.

Comment: BTW, there is no `svn ignore` command.

Comment: ````svn propset svn:ignore '*.*' .```` For abbreviating, I said simply: ````svn ignore````. Anyway, we're getting away from the point. How do I ignore files in subdirectories within Eclipse? Are you familiar with Subversive plugin of Eclipse? Kindly help on how I can do this.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am not familiar with Subversive for Eclipse. The workings of Subversion, however, are independent from the client which you use. What did happen when you *added* the directories before *ignoring* the PDFs? You may have to do a non-recursive add. If Subversive is not up to this task, consider installing `svn` command line client. It is included e.g. with TortoiseSVN's installer.

Comment: I have used the SVN cli on Linux. I use it to deploy the apps to dev, test & production servers. There I regularly add files & folders to the ignore property.
If I use a cli client on Windows or Tortoise, that still leaves Eclipse with partial capabilities.
I came across https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrQnsFfsaPY which mentions first committing everything then deleting from server and ignoring. I have the commit running atm. Let's wait & see...